# Solidity smart contract Cap Liquidity by %

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Is it possible to control the amount of liquidity a wallet can provide on a decentralized exchange like pancakeswap? I want to be able to limit the each wallet to max 3% of the total supply of 32 million. Any ideas on if that is possible? If so anyone have a suggestion on code?

I haven't tried anything yet as I am lost on this one.

Comment: Hey, other Stack Exchanges may be a better fit for you. The more in-the-loop people at [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/), or [Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help you on this. This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look over there.